# Complicated MySQL Database Query

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following database structure:

**Sites table**

```
id  |  name  |  other_fields
```

**Backups table**

```
id  |  site_id  | initiated_on(unix timestamp) | size(float) | status
```

So `Backups` table have a Many to One relationship with `Sites` table connected via `site_id`

---

And I would like to output the data in the following format

```
name | Latest initiated_on | status of the latest initiated_on row
```

And I have the following SQL query

```
SELECT *, `sites`.`id` as sid, SUM(`backups`.`size`) AS size
FROM (`sites`)
LEFT JOIN `backups` ON `sites`.`id` = `backups`.`site_id`
WHERE `sites`.`id` =  '1'
GROUP BY `sites`.`id`
ORDER BY `backups`.`initiated_on` desc
```

The thing is, with the above query I can achieve what I am looking for, but the only problem is I don't get the latest `initiated_on` values.

So if I had 3 rows in `backups` with `site_id`=`1`, the query does not pick out the row with the highest value in `initiated_on`. It just picks out any row.

Please help, and

thanks in advance.

Comment: You shouldn't write SELECT * when you have a GROUP BY - the values that you'll get back will be arbitrary. In most DBs this wouldn't even be a valid SQL statement. (And even when you aren't using GRUOP BY, SELECT * is still considered to be a bad practice).

Comment: can I change it to `SELECT sites.*` ?

Comment: You haven't added initiated_on  to your SELECT which is probably why it's not returning it.

Comment: you may use max(initiated_on) to get the maximum on a group by

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try:

```
SELECT sites.name, FROM_UNIXTIME(b.latest) as latest, b.size, b.status
FROM sites
LEFT JOIN
  ( SELECT bg.site_id, bg.latest, bg.sizesum AS size, bu.status
    FROM
      ( SELECT site_id, MAX(initiated_on) as latest, SUM(size) as sizesum
        FROM backups
        GROUP BY site_id ) bg
    JOIN backups bu
    ON bu.initiated_on = bg.latest AND bu.site_id = bg.site_id
  ) b
ON sites.id = b.site_id
```

1. In the `GROUP BY` subquery - `bg` here, the only columns you can use for `SELECT` are columns that are either aggregated by a function or listed in the `GROUP BY` part.

   http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/group-by-hidden-columns.html
2. Once you have all the aggregate values you need to join the result again to `backups` to find other values for the row with latest timestamp - `b`.
3. Finally join the result to the `sites` table to get names - or left join if you want to list all sites, even without a backup.

Comment: This is the most efficient solution but you should also add "bu.site_id = bg.site_id" to the innermost join

Comment: Yes you are right, I assumed int timestamp was unique enough, edited.

Comment: Thank you, well explained and the query is efficient in my crude benchmarking.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
select S.name, B.initiated_on, B.status
from sites as S left join backups as B on S.id = B.site_id
where B.initiated_on = 
       (select max(initiated_on)
           from backups
          where site_id = S.id)
```

Answer (score 1):

To get the latest time, you need to make a subquery like this:

```
    SELECT sites.id as sid, 
           SUM(backups.size) AS size
           latest.time AS latesttime
      FROM sites AS sites
 LEFT JOIN (SELECT site_id, 
                   MAX(initiated_on) AS time
              FROM backups
          GROUP BY site_id) AS latest
        ON latest.site_id = sites.id
 LEFT JOIN backups 
        ON sites.id = backups.site_id
     WHERE sites.id =  1
  GROUP BY sites.id
  ORDER BY backups.initiated_on desc
```

I have removed the SELECT * as this will only work using MySQL and is generally bad practice anyway. Non-MySQL RDBSs will throw an error if you include the other fields, even individually and you will need to make this query itself into a subquery and then do an INNER JOIN to the sites table to get the rest of the fields. This is because they will be trying to add all of them into the GROUP BY statement and this fails (or is at least very slow) if you have long text fields.

Comment: Oops! That was what I had in mind. Edited to use the right column name.